# android intent putextra wont pass my value

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android program that launches an intent and passes a value to the next activity.  I have done this before and it worked perfectly.  But on this occasion it is not passing the value.  I have used toast messages to see what happening and I cant figure out whats going on. Another question is in my other program that the intent.putextra worked the code

```
       Intent i= new Intent(this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
```

worked but in this program this gave me an error: "Remove arguments from intent" so i had to code it like:

```
      Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
```

my code is below. There are two activities Main and SpecialLocationDataBase:

```
   public class Main extends Activity {
   /** The activity that launches the intent and passes the value. */

TextView tv;

private SpecialLocationDatabaseHelper dbIngredientHelper=null;
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dbIngredientHelper = new SpecialLocationDatabaseHelper(this);
    dbIngredientHelper.createDatabase();


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            long choice=1;
            Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
            i.putExtra("choice", choice);
            //Main.this.startActivity(i);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

            Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                    "Here is your choice " + choice + " clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 




        }
     });

     final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            long choice=2;
            Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
            i.putExtra("choice", choice);
            Main.this.startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            long choice=3;
            Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
            i.putExtra("choice", choice);
            Main.this.startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            long choice=4;
            Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,SpecialLocationDatabase.class);
                i.putExtra("choice", choice);
            Main.this.startActivity(i);


        }
    });



    public class SpecialLocationDatabase extends ListActivity {
     /** The activity that is supposed to get the value. */


private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
    private SpecialLocationDatabaseHelper mDbHelper=null;

    long choice;

    private static final int BEGIN_SEARCH_OPTION = Menu.FIRST;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.specialloction);

    mDbHelper=new SpecialLocationDatabaseHelper(this);
    mDbHelper.openRead();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     choice = extras.getInt("choice");
        Toast.makeText(SpecialLocationDatabase.this,
                "NOw your choice " + choice + " clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fillData(choice);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {




            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `choice` as long, but reading it as `int`, you need to change one of them, for example:

```
long receivedChoice = extras.getLong("choice");
```

Regarding your other question - since the second time the intent was created inside a inner class, `this` has to be fully qualified (e.g. Main.this) to make it implicit that you are passing the Activity's `this` and not the listener's `this`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're using for the intent you're sending takes an application context. As the first respondent said, you have to disambiguate "this". I usually use getApplicationContext() instead of "this".

Also, it's not necessary to get all the Extras at once as a Bundle. There are methods for getting individual values from Extras according to their type. In your case, you could use getLongExtra(). getExtras() is meant to retrieve a whole Bundle of extras that were put into the Intent with putExtras(). In general, using putParceableArrayListExtra() and getParceableArrayListExtra() are more straightforward for sending a "map" of extras at once, and they also work between applications.

Comment: "I usually use getApplicationContext() instead of "this"" -- IMHO, that's a bad habit. While `getApplicationContext()` does return a `Context`, that `Context` is not suitable for many things, particularly related to the UI. IMHO, only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know exactly *why* `getApplicationContext()` is the right answer for a given situation. Otherwise, `this` is usually the right answer. It is also incrementally faster (no method invocation).